# SQL Query on math.SE: Upvoted questions where all answers are downvoted

Tags: support, down-votes, data-explorer

I tried to create a query in the data explorer to search all the questions that have at least one upvote, but where all the answers are downvoted.
Unfortunately my SQL is a bit rusty and the query I tried failed. Also I did not find out how to save it so it got lost somehow.
Any advice on how to create such a query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you want: https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/269442/upvoted-questions-where-all-answers-are-downvoted

```sql
SELECT
  p.Id AS [Post Link],
  MAX(p.Score) AS [Score],
  COUNT(a.Id) AS [AnswerCount],
  AVG(CAST(a.Score AS float)) AS [AvgAnswerScore]
FROM
  Posts AS p
  INNER JOIN Posts AS a
    ON p.Id = a.ParentId
WHERE
  p.Score >= 1
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Posts AS a2
    WHERE a2.ParentId = p.Id AND a2.Score >= 0
  )
GROUP BY
  p.Id
ORDER BY
  [Score] DESC,
  [AnswerCount] DESC
```

At the time of the last data dump, there were 390 questions of this kind on Math.SE.

> Also I did not find out how to save it so it got lost somehow.

Any query that is run on the Data Explorer should be saved automatically. In future, the "Revisions" pane in the sidebar of the editor may prove useful.